# is C2DM an Overkill or Unreliable for this?

Tags: android, google-play, android-c2dm

I want to remotely change few SharedPreference settings on my App.

I have been able to achieve this using SMS messages and corresponding broadcast listeners.

Now I want to use my app web server to do the same over the internet.

My question is, is google's C2DM the right choice for this task or it it an overkill or may be even unreliable for this job?

The objective is very simple. Send some kind of notification to the app that triggers a broadcast receiver. Parse the message received and based on the keyword in the message take some action(change SharedPreference settings in this case).

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C2DM does have its quirks, but for this purpose, I personally think c2dm is a good idea.

However you mentioned "unreliable" - one of c2dm's major drawback.
In [this introduction](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#intro), it's clearly mentioned that:

```
C2DM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages.
```

Although for the "overkill" part, i can guarantee that using android's c2dm architecture is way more simpler than implementing your own push notification implementation over persistent tcp/ip (check out this [article](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/)).

Answer (score 0):

C2DM is used for notifying really small messages like new offers,update version released etc. C2DM is loosely based for just updating app from market(now Google play), as far the reliability matters, it will not be the best choice to do it cos you have to sync your app with user's Google account, ultimately what your app server will do is, it will send message first to C2DM server and then C2DM will send the message to you and C2DM is the central for all other apps too like you, So it may happen that your message can not reach to mobile if something goes wrong to C2DM server. So its better not rely on C2DM and find your own way for push notification of your app such as when application starts it searches for any update or anything via service and do needful on based of service's response